# If router is in bridge mode, is it still emitting EMF?

Tags: wireless-router, bridge, cable-modem

I have an Arris Surfboard SBG7400, and I put it in Bridge mode so as to avoid EMF radiation from keeping the router on (I live in a tiny place and it's in my bedroom).  But my Wifi is still picking up the signal, even though it can't connect.  Does that mean it's still emitting EMF, even though I'm now in Bridge mode?

Comment: That has to do with Wireless, not Bridge Mode.  I see lots of wireless with inSSider that I cannot connect to, so likely nothing to worry about.  If it is ON, wireless will broadcast

Comment: Welcome. First of all this question stems from an unfounded fear, no doubt propelled by so many scammers and scientific illiterate "alternative" media (and mainstream media occasionally). Secondly, modes have nothing to do with it. You need to disable WiFi if the router's firmware allows it if you don't want WiFi. But you can't disable any access point you don't have control over nor turn off the sun, background radiation, etc. You can stop eating bananas though, those emit a lot more radiation than most of the electronics you fear.

Comment: Radiation to "fear" is much shorter in wavelength that anything computers use.  Short wavelength X-Rays.

Comment: LOL. Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 4):

Every single electrical device releases EMF.

"Bridge" Mode in this case is meant for people who don't want the system to act as a router - if you have another router.

While to most 'non techie' folks - a router is a 'wireless' router, wireless is generally a separate, 'bolted on' function that's nothing to do with routing.

Your Arris Surfboard is a Cable Modem + Router + Access Point (or Wifi) - if you don't want wireless you should need to turn out off seperately. That said, your wifi card is also emitting (entirely harmless) 2.4 or 5 gig radio signals.

If you're worried about actual EMF - While devices are often shielded, every switch mode power supply, motor and electrical device in your apartment is generating EMF. There's EMF in the air. The earth's magnetic field is an EMF. Its everywhere, and its a force that makes life possible (Mars has no magnetic field at the moment, and that's one reason its a barren lifeless rock)

So - the wireless being detected is likely a misconfiguration. There's lots of great reasons *to* turn off wireless in such devices, but 'reducing EMF' isn't really one of them.

The only way to really 'minimise' EMF for whatever reason is to turn off at the switch *anything* with a power brick or any electronics whatsoever when not in use, and shielding your walls. And practically there's no real benefit from this other than a few cents off your power bill.

Comment: Your wireless phone, cellular phone, and microwave all emit EMF radiation. It’s estimated that a lifetime of exposure to these types of of devices are equivalent to the radiation you would receive from a single X-Ray